# Jquery datepicker not fetching values when the user clicks once

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

Am using Jquery Datepicker to fetch dates from the user which works fine. The problem is that I have to click more than once (doubleclick) so that the date value can be captured.

I want when the user selects the date once from the datepicker it displays without double-click effect..

~ Kindly assist?

**Layout**

```
<input type="text-area" placeholder="Child Date Of Birth" class="form-input dateTextBox" name="childdob" id="childDob" value="{{ old('childdob') }}" autocomplete="off">
```

**Jquery Datepicker code**

```
$( function() {
      $( "#childDob" ).datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        //yy-mm-dd
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        yearRange: "-18:+0",
        maxDate: "0",
      });
  });
```

Comment: show code sample or jsfiddle

Comment: Do you want to hide datepicker when you click??

Comment: @Karan  I want to fetch the date value when the user clicks on the date once

Comment: what is "text-area" in the type? this is not a valid type.

Answer (score 1):

change input type to text, it will work

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Child Date Of Birth" class="form-input dateTextBox" name="childdob" id="childDob" value="{{ old('childdob') }}" autocomplete="off">
```